# Logical Test, time

Tags: algebra-precalculus

if the digestion speed of A is 1 minute, B 2 minutes, C 3 minutes, and D 5 minutes. and the total of food is 20, what is the fastest time for the team that consists of A,B,C, and D to digest all of the foods?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Let's suppose that the total eating time is $T$ minutes.
In $T$ minutes, $A$ will digest $\frac{T}{1}$ items of food. $B$ will digest $\frac{T}{2}$ items of food. $C$ will digest $\frac{T}{3}$ items of food. $D$ will digest $\frac{T}{5}$ items of food.

So in total, they will digest
$$
\frac{T}{1} + \frac{T}{2} + \frac{T}{3} + \frac{T}{5} = 20
$$
items of food. Can you continue from here?

Comment: 10 or 11 i guess, thanks for the hint sir